# How can I create and assign a SQL Server user during EF Core runtime database creation?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-migrations

I need to know how to create a SQL Server database, and a new SQL Server user, and assign that user to the database as `db_owner` when my .NET Core application first runs using Entity Framework Core migrations (currently these steps are done manually before first deployment).

I'm trying to automate the database creation and user creation upon first run to save our implementations analyst steps. Also, I'd like some guidance if this is even best practice. We don't have a DBA and I am not allowed into the SQL Server to manually create everything that is needed.

I've tried to inject `Sql()` commands into the `Up()` method of my first migration, but since the connection string already has the SQL Server credentials of the user I'm trying to create manually, the login obviously failed.

I'm assuming I'll need to use Windows authentication of some sort to the SQL Server to create the database and user, but I'm not sure how to use Windows authentication for the migrations and SQL Server authentication for the rest of the application.

Here's the `Up()` code that I've tried:

```
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{
    migrationBuilder.Sql("CREATE LOGIN svc_appname_env WITH PASSWORD = 'app_password'");
    migrationBuilder.Sql("CREATE USER [svc_appname_env] FOR LOGIN [svc_appname_env]");
    migrationBuilder.Sql("EXECUTE sp_addrolemember N'db_owner', N'svc_appname_env'");
    ...
}
```

In `Startup.cs`:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    using (var serviceScope = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope())
    {
        var context = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<MyDatabaseContext>();
        context.Database.Migrate();
    }
    ...
}
```

I expect the user and database to be created, but instead I'm getting the following error:

> Login failed for user 'svc_appname_env'

Comment: You misspelled CREATE (CRATE).  What is the value of svc_appname_env?

Comment: @jdweng Good catch.  I've updated the original post with the correct spelling.

Comment: You must have 2 connection string in your application, one of them for migration that use windows authentication and the other one for application user sql authentication with user that you create in migration. for more information about connection string see this https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/

Comment: @jdweng It's the SQL Server service account name that I want to create.  I just renamed it to something generic for the purposes of putting it on the Internet.  In my actual app, it is svc_myappname_dev, to match the development environment and the app name.

Comment: @Hadi That's what I was thinking I'd need to do.  I do see the box in the Publish screen that contains a different connection string for the migrations.

Comment: Opps. please see @jdweng comment. you write `CRATE` instead of `CREATE` for creating user

Comment: You need an Admin to create a new instance of the SQL Server.  If you are just adding a database to an existing server then you just need to : Create Database XYZ